# How to reset TCP/IP on Windows 8.1?

Tags: networking, powershell, windows-8.1, netsh

The following netsh command is not working on Windows 8.1.

**netsh int ipv4 reset**

It give “Access Denied” error and it is a VERY known issue, many people complaining about it all ove online forums.

There is no known equivalent PowerShell command. 
One tedious solution is to use Process Monitor and track the registry that it needs to have

access to and grant access. This is not practical since the registry key includes a random guid on each machine.

What is the practical remedy for this?

Update:

@grawity, I tried the command in the elevated mode - Of course

Comment: PowerShell? `netsh` is a standalone command, it should work in *any* shell.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve with this command?  Perhaps there is a different approach.

Comment: @Paul: This command fixes many networking issues and rebuilds all P stack registry settings. I have been in many situations where the network access was slow or not working and this command did the magic. The fact that it stopped working on Win8.1 should not force us to question its use.

Comment: @grawity: Running this command in powershell shell produces the same "Access Denied" result. However, it helps if we have an equivalent PowerShell command to reset IP stack. I couldn't find ant.

Comment: ...did you run it in an elevated shell or a regular one?

Comment: @AllanXu I am not questioning its use but it sounds like a driver issue from your description, and so addressing the underlying issue is an alternative approach to solving the problem.

Comment: @AllanXu  Have you tried this with a local or domain admin account?  I know, it's a long time ago....but I love the netsh cmd and it caught my eye.  I'm thinking something wrong with impersonation??  Just a thought.

Comment: @Citizen, I did this with local admin. Doing it with a domain admin is not an option for me.

Comment: Try this: run regedit and go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nsi\{eb004a00-9b1a-11d4-9123-0050047759bc}26  Right click "26" properties, make sure "everyone" has full control. exit regedit  then type"netsh int ip reset C:\resetlog.txt" from an elevated prompt, it should work. then reboot.

Answer (score 1):

With Powershell you could almost make your own command. Something like this might help:

```
$netadapt = Get-CimInstance CIM_NetworkAdapter | ? {$_.AdapterType -eq "Ethernet 802.3"}
$netadapt.Disable()
$netadapt.Enable()
```

The only caveat with this is that it's going to reset all network adapters that are "Ethernet 802.3". If that's an issue you can substitute `$_.AdapterType` with `$_.name` and also replace `"Ethernet 802.3"` with an actual device name e.g. `"Intel(R) 82579V Gigabit Network Connection."`

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this problem with PowerShell. Just run [the command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826145.aspx):

```
Remove-NetIPAddress
```

Comment: It worked to me